# Dataframe Adjustment

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, matrix, adjacency-matrix

I have a dataframe with similar row and column labels just like any other square matrix as it follows:

```
    a  b  c  d  e  f

a   1  1  0  1  0  1
b   0  0  0  0  0  1
c   0  1  1  0  1  0
d   1  0  0  1  1  0
e   0  1  1  0  0  0
f   0  0  0  1  0  1
```

How to convert this dataframe into another form (by rearranging rows and columns) where all the non-zero diagonal elements are all in the lower block and zero diagonal elements in the upper block? In other words, the matrix has been permuted so that "1" diagonal elements are in the lower block and the "0" diagonal elements are in upper block such as the following:

```
    b  e  a  c  d  f

b   0  0  0  0  0  1
e   1  0  0  1  0  0
a   1  0  1  0  1  1
c   1  1  0  1  0  0
d   0  1  1  0  1  0
f   0  0  0  0  1  1
```

Comment: can you provide the expected output?

Comment: Your latex isn't showing up right on SO...will you please convert to the actual text output you'd expect?

Comment: Just provided the expected output. "0" diagonal up and "1" diagonal down.

Comment: @Roosha thanks for the update, see below for a solution ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you can extract the diagonal of the underlying numpy array and get the sorted order with [`numpy.argsort`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html), then slice with `iloc`:

```
import numpy as np
order = np.argsort(df.to_numpy().diagonal())

df2 = df.iloc[order, order]
```

output:

```
   b  e  a  c  d  f
b  0  0  0  0  0  1
e  1  0  0  1  0  0
a  1  0  1  0  1  1
c  1  1  0  1  0  0
d  0  1  1  0  1  0
f  0  0  0  0  1  1
```

Comment: I could have not thought of the first line to make the order. Thank you! it's very interesting.